# Как получить все роли сервера Discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api, discord

Пишу бота для дискорда. Нужно получить все роли сервера.
Есть код:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"),
      client = new Discord.Client();

client.login("myToken");

client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(client.guilds);
});
```

Данный код выводит в консоль следующее:[image: Результат работы кода]

Так вот, как получить свойство roles? Пытался писать `client.guilds.roles`, но в таком случае возвращается `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.guilds.get('ID нужного сервера').roles`

Бот обязательно должен быть участником сервера, иначе ничего не выйдет.

Для ваших нужд есть отличная документация (одна из самых лучших, что я видел) https://discord.js.org

Не ленитесь гуглить ваш вопрос ибо до вас его уже задавали многие участники, а так-же есть много статей в интернете. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300358/js-discord-bot-get-role